# How do I group sentences depending on the label?

Tags: python

If I have set of sentences in a file such as :

```
1 let's go shopping
1 what a wonderful day
1 let's party tonight
2 nobody went there
2 it was a deserted place
3 lets go tomorrow
4 what tomorrow
4 ok sure let's see
```

I want to group these sentences in a group. Like all the sentences belonging to label '1' should be in one group and those in '2' in another.

So I am loading for file like this:

```
result=[]
with open("sentences.txt","r") as filer:
    for line in filer:
        result.append(line.strip().split())
```

so I get something like this:

```
[['1', 'let's',  'go',  'shopping'], 
['1', 'what',  'a',  'wonderful',  'day'],
['1', 'let's', 'party', 'tonight'],
['2', 'nobody', 'went', 'there']]
```

Now I want something like this:

```
for line in result:
    if line[0]== '1':
        process(line)
    elif line[0]=='2':
        process(line)
    elif line[0]=='4':
        process(line)
    elif line[0]=='3':
        process(line)
```

But the problem with this is that it is considering one sentence at a time. I want all the '1' in a group and then run the process(function) on them.

File 1:

```
[['1', 'in', 'seattle', 'today', 'the', 'secretary', 'of', 'education', 'richard', 'riley', 'delivered', 'his', 'address', 'on', 'the', 'state', 'of', 'american', 'education'], ['1', 'one', 'of', 'the', 'things', 'he', 'focused', 'on', 'as', 'the', 'president', 'had', 'done', 'in', 'his', 'state', 'of', 'the', 'union', 'was', 'the', 'goal', 'to', 'reduce', 'the', 'size', 'of', 'the', 'average', 'class']]
```

File 2:

```
[['1', 'in', 'seattl', 'today', 'the', 'secretari', 'of', 'educ', 'richard', 'riley', 'deliv', 'hi', 'address', 'on', 'the', 'state', 'of', 'american', 'educ'], ['1', 'one', 'of', 'the', 'thing', 'he', 'focus', 'on', 'a', 'the', 'presid', 'had', 'done', 'in', 'hi', 'state', 'of', 'the', 'union', 'wa', 'the', 'goal', 'to', 'reduc', 'the', 'size', 'of', 'the', 'averag', 'class']]
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
from collections import defaultdict

result = defaultdict(list)
with open("sentences.txt","r") as filer:
    for line in filer:
        label, sentence = line.strip().split(' ', 1)
        result[label].append(sentence)
```

then you can process it with:

```
for label, sentences in result.items():
    # bla bla bla
```

Comment: Hi, may I ask why is there a 1 in the line.strip.split(' ', 1)? Are u referring to the label 1, if yes, i have a number of labels so would it have to be modified for each and every label?

Comment: @minks no, `1` here is the max split times:  https://docs.python.org/2/library/stdtypes.html#str.split

Comment: `'a b c'.split(' ', 1)` results in `['a', 'b c']` while `'a b c'.split(' ', 2)` results in `['a', 'b', 'c']`

Comment: Oh! I understand it now! Thanks a ton!

Comment: Just one more question. I try the above code with one file, it works but when I am trying it with another file in the exact same format, it is showing me an error saying:    label, sentence= line.strip().split(' ', 1)
ValueError: need more than 1 value to unpack

The other file is in the exact same format as shown above.

Comment: @minks seems the other file has lines not in the exact same format.. can you paste it somewhere?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105673/discussion-between-minks-and-wong2).

Comment: I have added the format of the two files in the edited question.